# 他クラス線形回帰に対する最急降下法

Tags: python, 機械学習

タイトル通り線形回帰に対して最急降下法を行いました。もちろん解析的に解は出せるんですが、それはここでは置いておいてください。

目的関数は

```
$$ \frac{1}{2} \| Xb - y \|_2^2 $$
```

であり、その勾配は

```
$$ X^T X b - X^T y $$
```

となります。これを用いて最急降下法を行いましたが、最小化されません。むしろコストが上がっていきます。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mubaris/potential-enigma/master/student.csv')

x = data['Math'].values
y = data['Reading'].values
z = data['Writing'].values

def costf(X, y, param):
    return np.sum((X.dot(param) - y) ** 2)/2.

interc = np.ones(1000)
X = np.concatenate([interc.reshape(-1, 1), x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)], axis=1)

param = np.array([0,0,0])

 def gradient_descent(X, y, param, eta=0.001, iter=10):
    cost_history = [0] * iter

    for iteration in xrange(iter):
        h = X.dot(param)
        loss = h - y
        gradient = X.T.dot(loss)
        param = param - eta * gradient
        cost = costf(X, y, param)
        print cost
        cost_history[iteration] = cost

    return param, cost_history
```

どこがおかしいのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最急降下法が発散するということであれば、単純に学習率が高いということではないですかね。eta=0.001をもう少し低い値にしてみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: 小さくしてもダメです、最小化されず増加してしまいます

Comment: 勾配とコストを`m(=len(y))`で割ってないからですかね。

Comment: mで割ってもだめでした。どうしてでしょう、

Comment: `return np.sum((X.dot(param) - y) ** 2)/2.`を`return np.sum((X.dot(param) - y) ** 2)/(2 * len(y))`に、`gradient = X.T.dot(loss)`を`gradient = X.T.dot(loss)/len(y)`に、`eta=0.001`を`eta=0.0001`とかさらにもっと小さい値に変えても駄目ですか？

Comment: そう思いましたが、だめです、増えます

Comment: コードがやはり間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: @JapaneseStudent 私の手元では、その Kohei TAMURA さんの修正でちゃんと減りました。

Comment: こちらに少しミスがありました。問題解決しました。ありがとうございます